# What do the different types of musgrave texture do?

Tags: procedural

The musgrave texture properties let's one choose between 5 types of perlin noise. While FBM is just the Fractal Brownian Motion we all know and love it also offers other types like `Hetero terrain` or `Multifractal` which I have never heard of.

What I want to know is how those types of perlin noise are generated mathematically, as there are already enough tutorials on Youtube, which vaguely describe how these noise types look.

You can assume that I know how Perlin noise is generated.

Edit: Quellenform found the source code in question: https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/dfb8c90324c018068f12ca41543c3c311dff6d21/source/blender/blenlib/intern/noise.cc#L747

Thanks!